# How can we make our fork our canonical upstream in Github?

Tags: git, github

I was working late one Friday night and came upon a requirement that I realized should be its own small app. I do not have access to the company Github account, so I started a repo on my own account. I worked all weekend and I had the app done by Monday morning. I sent an email to someone at the company who controls the company Github account. I asked that they fork my repo. They did so, so now the company had my code. Then I ran "git remote add upstream" so my repo would point to the company repo.

All was good.

The next week, I wrote more code, and pushed it to my repo. Then I went to make a pull request. But Github didn't give me the option of making a pull request against the fork, which was now my upstream.

What do I need to do to mark that fork as my canonical upsteam to which I will make pull requests?

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I found it. I guess when you create the repo, and then hit the "Pull Request" button, Github defaults to comparing branches in the same repo, whereas when you are working on a fork, Github defaults to comparing across forks, but you can click a "Compare across forks" button, even when you started the repo.